# How to substract/except two jQuery queries?

Tags: jquery

**Context**

I have two jQuery queries in variables `$menu` and `$current`. The query `$menu` includes some DOM elements what are in the `$current` query also.

I would like to execute something on all `$menu` elements *except* on `$current` elements.

The sample pseudo code:

```
($menu - $current).toggleClass('open');
```

**Question**

Is it possible in jQuery?

Comment: No, it's not, Please try to give as a sample of code for your case...

Comment: Thanks. In selector level I can manage the solution, just thought it maybe it can be done in query level.

Comment: Note that you don't have **selectors** stored in those variables. You have the **results** of doing DOM queries with selectors, which (in jQuery) are jQuery objects.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thx, I was aware of that, and edited the title in advance, but the question text was still using the 'selector' term. I've already corrected that too, adding the credit for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

> Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

```
$menu.not($current).toggleClass('open');
```

**Demo**

```js
var $menu = $("li")
var $current = $("#notli")

$menu.not($current).css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li id="notli">list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and `is` to construct a new jQuery object, based on a test of whether the element being iterated over is included in the other object:

```
$menu
  .filter(function() {
    return !$(this).is($current);
  })
  .toggleClass('open');
```

Comment: Yeah, should be `.not` (see User863's answer), not `filter`. My bad.